# Pytest do not wrap test in transaction

Tags: python, transactions, pytest

When using pytest with fixture `@pytest.mark.django_db`, I see pytest automatically wraps the test in transaction. This disallows me to test functions with `transaction.on_commit()`, because `on_commit()` will not actually be applied after test is done. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

By checking the [documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest.mark.django_db) I've seen that there is a `transaction` argument that is set to `False` by default. By setting it to `True` it will actually run transactions -- I guess.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
```